# postMapping won't add new object to PostgreSQl DB, SpringBoot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, rest

I have SpringBoot+PostgreSQL app with REST and all methods except PostMapping work well. I'm already rechecked all sources that I take info from, and it looks correct to me. Im newbie at Spring and maybe just missed some small detail.idk

Add all files that my project consist of:

DAOImpl a.k.a. Repository

```
 @Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Employee");
        List<Employee> allEmployees=query.getResultList();
        return allEmployees;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        Employee newEmployee = entityManager.merge(employee);
        employee.setEmployeeId(newEmployee.getEmployeeId());
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getEmployee(int employeeId) {
        Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, employeeId);
        return employee;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteEmployee(int employeeId) {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("delete from Employee "+ "where employeeId=:employeeId");
        query.setParameter("employeeId",employeeId);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Integer employeeId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "department_id")
    private Integer departmentId;

    @Column(name = "job_title")
    private String jobTitle;

    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Integer getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(Integer departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public String getJobTitle() {
        return jobTitle;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String jobTitle) {
        this.jobTitle = jobTitle;
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("sayhello")
    public String sayHello(){
        return "Hello world";
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
        List<Employee> allEmployees = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
        return allEmployees;
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees/{employeeId}")
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable int employeeId){
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployee(employeeId);

        return employee;
    }

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee addNewEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return employee;
    }

    @PutMapping("/employees")
    public Employee updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee){
        employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
        return employee;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/employees/{employeeId}")
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable int employeeId){
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(employeeId);

        return "Employee with ID = " + employeeId + " was deleted";
    }



}
```

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    @Autowired private EmployeeDAO employeeDao;
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees(){
        return employeeDao.getAllEmployees();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee){
        employeeDao.saveEmployee(employee);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Employee getEmployee(int employeeId){
        return employeeDao.getEmployee(employeeId);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteEmployee(int employeeId){
        employeeDao.deleteEmployee(employeeId);
    }



}
```

How my db Employee looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSGNT.png

So here errors from postman when i tried to add new employee

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-07-03T12:47:39.419+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)\r\n\tat com.example.demo.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20b8e2cf.saveEmployee(<generated>)\r\n\tat com.example.demo.service.EmployeeService.saveEmployee(EmployeeService.java:21)\r\n\tat com.example.demo.service.EmployeeService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a2443614.invoke(<generated>)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)\r\n\tat com.example.demo.service.EmployeeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$363f298d.saveEmployee(<generated>)\r\n\tat com.example.demo.rest.EmployeeController.addNewEmployee(EmployeeController.java:35)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:79)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator$1.getNextValue(TableGenerator.java:583)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator.generate(TableGenerator.java:579)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:115)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:243)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:175)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:829)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy94.merge(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)\r\n\tat jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy94.merge(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.example.demo.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.saveEmployee(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:25)\r\n\tat com.example.demo.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f8b5a20e.invoke(<generated>)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\t... 66 more\r\nCaused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation \"hibernate_sequences\" does not exist\n  Position: 26\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:167)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:119)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator.executeQuery(TableGenerator.java:714)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator.access$400(TableGenerator.java:131)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator$1$1.execute(TableGenerator.java:598)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator$1$1.execute(TableGenerator.java:584)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)\r\n\t... 92 more\r\n",
    "message": "error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work",
    "path": "/employees/"
}
```

And this one from intellij

```
2022-07-03 15:09:57.971  WARN 16984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2022-07-03 15:09:57.971 ERROR 16984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "employee_id" of relation "employee" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, Johnny, Depp, 11, Actor).
2022-07-03 15:09:57.987 ERROR 16984 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [employee_id" of relation "employee]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "employee_id" of relation "employee" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null, Johnny, Depp, 11, Actor).
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:167) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:135) ~[postgresql-42.3.6.jar:42.3.6]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3885) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:829) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy94.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy94.merge(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.demo.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.saveEmployee(EmployeeDAOImpl.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f8b5a20e.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at com.example.demo.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$85b40f44.saveEmployee(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.service.EmployeeService.saveEmployee(EmployeeService.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.service.EmployeeService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a2443614.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708) ~[spring-aop-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at com.example.demo.service.EmployeeService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$391eac97.saveEmployee(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.rest.EmployeeController.addNewEmployee(EmployeeController.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
```

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- The exception message is quite on-point: the primary key is `null`.

Comment: (If I had to guess, I'd say the problem occurs because `entityManager.merge(...)` is used instead of `entityManger.save(...)`)

Comment: @Turing85 Yeah, but why if i defined pk as 2 (|employeeId": 2)
And this method need to update and add, so it cant be only for save

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your point. The field `employeeId` is defined as `GeneratedValue`, so we should avoid setting it explicitly (for new entities). Furthermore, `EntityManager::merge` it to update some state with an existing (!) state in the persistence context, `EntityManager::persist` is to create a new(!) entity in the persistence context (which is what we want in this case).

Comment: @Turing85, in course that a watch to learn springboot, man use merge instead of SaveOrUpdate from Session. Said that it work in the same way. btw will try persist now

upd. didnt work

Comment: A possible problem could be that the auto-incrementation is not properly configured in the the database schema. See [the documentation of `@GenerationType`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/persistence/generationtype) for details.

Comment: @Turing85 It is, im just delete this line with GenerationType from my Entity file and that it, i just need to add id manually. it is so stupid

Comment: This is not the proper way. The primary key is (normally) a database-concern and should thus be handled by the database. Otherwise, we might run into problems, e.g. when the application is restarted ro when multiple instances of our application try to persist concurrently with the same primary key.

Comment: @Turing85 fixed! problem was with db, the primary key was not serial.